# Virtualbox hangs when shutting down after having installed guest editions

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, shutdown, virtualization, crash

I have had a few Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VMs running on my windows 7 host and it's been great. I just recently added the guest additions to one of the Ubuntu guests on virtual box and now every time I try to shutdown windows tells me that the virtual box has stopped working.

What do i need to do to solve the problem and keep my guest additions?

Comment: Close-voters: as it appears [the problem was with the Ubuntu guest](http://askubuntu.com/a/440378/22949)--rather than the Windows host or VirtualBox itself--this is almost certainly on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try lo log in the VM where you installed the guest additions and re-install them using their packaged versions:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Finally restart the VM to complete the installation.

Comment: OMG! It worked! I was so surprised! I already had the first two packages, but it was the last package that helped. The first time I shutdown the VM it failed again, but after that everything seems to shutdown perfectly. Is there any more explanation as to why this works?

Comment: From my own experience installing guest additions inside the VM with the VM package manager gives better results that the VirtualBox ISO.

Comment: So I called Devices -> Install guest additions from the virtual box menubar, then the guest additions disc popped into ubuntu and I ran the VBoxLinuxAdditions file. How is that different?

Comment: I don't know how VB iso are built but virtualbox-guest-* packages are maintained in Debian and Ubuntu and could sometimes provides Ubuntu specific fixes.